# Slow compile time in Xcode in specific methods

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using Xcode 8.2.1 and I have been getting extremely slow compile time for my last project. I spent some time researching why this was happening and I started tracking the compile time of my project. So the main problem seems to be here:

> 49,609.4ms to compile moveIcons()

Now this was a bit of a surprise to me since moveIcons() is not really an extensive method:

```
func moveIcons(_ motion : SlideMotion) {
    var direction : CGFloat = 1
    if motion == .Out {
        direction = -1
    }
    for icon in 0...3 {
        let currentIcon = pauseIcons[icon]
        var moveAction = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: (-scene.size.width * direction * 0.26) - (scene.size.width * 0.18 * direction), dy: 0), duration: 0.2), SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: scene.size.width * direction * 0.18, dy: 0), duration: 0.1)])
        if icon == 3 {
            moveAction = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -scene.size.width * direction, dy: 0), duration: 0.3), SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: scene.size.width * direction * 0.25, dy: 0), duration: 0.15)])
        }
        currentIcon.run(moveAction)
    }
}
```

*pauseIcons is initialized like this: (and it probably holds like 4 objects)

```
var pauseIcons : [SKSpriteNode] = []
```

Now I thought maybe the issue is because type inferencing is slowing down the build. Therefore, I did this:

```
func moveIcons(_ motion : SlideMotion) {
    var direction : CGFloat = 1
    if motion == .Out {
        direction = -1
    }
    for icon in 0...3 {
        let currentIcon : SKSpriteNode = pauseIcons[icon]
        var moveAction : SKAction = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: (-scene.size.width * direction * 0.26) - (scene.size.width * 0.18 * direction), dy: 0), duration: 0.2), SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: scene.size.width * direction * 0.18, dy: 0), duration: 0.1)])
        if icon == 3 {
            moveAction = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -scene.size.width * direction, dy: 0), duration: 0.3), SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: scene.size.width * direction * 0.25, dy: 0), duration: 0.15)])
        }
        currentIcon.run(moveAction)
    }
}
```

However compile time is still the highest of my project:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea of **why this particular method takes so much time to compile?**

Comment: Slow compile times with deeply nested expressions have been a known issue with Swift.  (Have you tried the current version of Xcode?)  Annotating the lvalue can't hurt, but it doesn't really help the other dozen inferences on each line.  In line 8, for example, you're doing 8 arithmetic operations, when you only need to do 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression and the related one are very complicated:

```
var moveAction = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: (-scene.size.width * direction * 0.26) - (scene.size.width * 0.18 * direction), dy: 0), duration: 0.2), SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: scene.size.width * direction * 0.18, dy: 0), duration: 0.1)])
```

Break these up with intermediate variables. The problem isn't figuring out the final type. The problem is working out all the possibilities for `*` and `-`. Yes, there is only one *valid* possibility, but the compiler has to check *every* possible combination of types to make sure that the expression isn't ambiguous. In particular, it has to do a lot of work deciding whether `0.26` should be a `CGFloat`, `Float`, or `Double`.

Something more along these lines:

```
for icon in 0...3 {
    let currentIcon : SKSpriteNode = pauseIcons[icon]

    let moveAction: SKAction

    if icon == 3 {
        let moveBy1 = CGVector(dx: -scene.size.width * direction, dy: 0)
        let moveBy2 = CGVector(dx: scene.size.width * direction * 0.25, dy: 0)
        moveAction = SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.move(by: moveBy1), duration: 0.3),
            SKAction.move(by: moveBy2, duration: 0.15)])
    } else {
        let moveBy1 = CGVector(dx: (-scene.size.width * direction * 0.26) - (scene.size.width * 0.18 * direction), dy: 0)
        let moveBy2 = CGVector(dx: scene.size.width * direction * 0.18, dy: 0)
        moveAction = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.move(by: moveBy1, duration: 0.2),
                                        SKAction.move(by: moveBy2, duration: 0.1)])
    }
    currentIcon.run(moveAction)
}
```

Comment: Will try it out and run another scan. Thank you for the suggestion. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I'd simplify `(-scene.size.width * direction * 0.26) - (scene.size.width * 0.18 * direction)` -- this can be half as many operations, if you just combine the common factors.

Comment: For that matter, I'd compute `scene.size.width * direction` once, because it's used so many places.

Comment: This answer, along with your comment @Ssswift, was a life saver. I also cast all of those literals, such as 0.26, to CGFloat(0.26) and helped a lot.